# How do i resolve this procedure or function 'SelectFollow' expects parameter '@userid', which was not supplied.'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I am trying to get the current userid from the parameter and to check if it exists in a Database Table using stored procedure

```csharp
public PartialViewResult AllStates(string state, string userid)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    Following following = new Following();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = userid;
    List<Farmer> model = db.Farmer.Where(u => u.FarmState == state).Take(3).ToList();
    var modelfollow = db.Following.SqlQuery("[dbo].[SelectFollow]").ToList();
    ViewBag.folo = modelfollow;
    return PartialView("_UsersList", model );
}
```

This is my stored Procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE SelectFollow 
    @userid INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @HasFollowed BIT
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Followings Where UserId = @userid)
BEGIN
SET @HasFollowed = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @HasFollowed = 0
END
END
GO
```

Is there any thing I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah... not passing the parameters to the sproc, exactly as the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line, which doesn't include any stored procedure (SP) parameter while the SP requires one parameter, hence the exception mentioned in the title has thrown:

```csharp
var modelfollow = db.Following.SqlQuery("[dbo].[SelectFollow]").ToList();
```

Also you're adding parameter to `SqlCommand` instance which contains empty query string (and you're not execute it afterwards):

```csharp
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = userid;
```

Since you're using [`DbSet.SqlQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads) method, you may pass query parameter(s) as second parameter of that method by declaring [`SqlParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) instance:

```csharp
public PartialViewResult AllStates(string state, string userid)
{
    // define stored procedure parameter here
    var parameter = new SqlParameter("@userid", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    parameter.Value = userid;

    List<Farmer> model = db.Farmer.Where(u => u.FarmState == state).Take(3).ToList();

    // use stored procedure parameter declared above
    var modelfollow = db.Following.SqlQuery("[dbo].[SelectFollow] @userid", parameter).ToList();
    ViewBag.folo = modelfollow;
    return PartialView("_UsersList", model);
}
```

Comment: If you have another problem, just create a new question by linking to this one. Also you may consider to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the provided answer deemed helpful.

Comment: Ok, but how do i link a question to this one

Comment: Please help me how do i come out of this "You have reached your question limit Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."